# Declaration of SearchableBehavior::beforeSave() should be compatible with ModelBehavior::beforeSave(Model $model, $options = Array)

Tags: cakephp, behavior, searchable-plugin

I am using [Searchable-Behaviour-for-CakePHP](https://github.com/connrs/Searchable-Behaviour-for-CakePHP)

**The plugin eject error:**

Strict (2048): Declaration of SearchableBehavior::beforeSave() should be compatible with ModelBehavior::beforeSave(Model $model, $options = Array) [APP/Plugin/Searchable/Model/Behavior/SearchableBehavior.php, line 5]

Strict (2048): Declaration of SearchableBehavior::afterSave() should be compatible with ModelBehavior::afterSave(Model $model, $created, $options = Array) [APP/Plugin/Searchable/Model/Behavior/SearchableBehavior.php, line 5]

**The line 5 into SearchableBehavior.php is:**

```
class SearchableBehavior extends ModelBehavior { // Line 5
public $__defaultSettings = array(
    'foreignKey' => false,
    '_index' => false,
    'rebuildOnUpdate' => true,
    'fields' => '*',
    'stopwords_lang' => 'es'
);
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Change the method signature

Probably that plugin was created for an earlier version of CakePHP. The error reads:

> Strict (2048): Declaration of SearchableBehavior::beforeSave() should be compatible with ModelBehavior::beforeSave(Model $model, $options = Array) [APP/Plugin/Searchable/Model/Behavior/SearchableBehavior.php, line 5]

I.e. [in the searchable behavior](https://github.com/connrs/Searchable-Behaviour-for-CakePHP/blob/master/Model/Behavior/SearchableBehavior.php#L44) there is this:

```
public function beforeSave(Model $Model) {
```

And instead it should be changed to

```
public function beforeSave(Model $model, $options = Array) {
```

That kind of warning will always be shown whenever a child class redefines a method and give s it a different signature.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
public function beforeSave(Model $model, $options = Array()) {
```